# VB.net is it possible to catch a thrown exception from a public class

Tags: vb.net, exception

I am writing a program that makes use of a vb class.
In some cases this class does do a `Throw New ArgumentException("Error xyz")`

I do not want to edit this class, and like to keep it as is.
As the class is used by other programs too.

My new program should have a try catch so that it catches that thrown exception. I tried to put a command from the class inside a try catch construction in my main application, but i still get an exception popup from the class, its not catched.

Is there a way to catch those throw new exception from a subclass ?

Some more explaining
I use an existing peace of code DeviceHelper.vb
That code starts with

```
  Imports USBControl.NativeMethods
  Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
  Imports System.ComponentModel
  Imports System.Text

  Public NotInheritable Class DeviceHelper
```

And in it there is a private sub SetDeviceEnabled

```
   Private Shared Sub EnableDevice(ByVal handle As SafeDeviceInfoSetHandle, ByVal diData As DeviceInfoData, ByVal enable As Boolean)
```

That does contain a line

```
  Throw New ArgumentException("That device can't be disabled! Look in the device manager!")
```

My main program uses Devicehelper.vbs but it cant catch an exception like

```
   Try
   DeviceHelper.SetDeviceEnabled(DeviceGuid, deviceID, False)
   Catch ex As Exception
   Console.Writeline(ex.Message)
   End Try
```

Comment: So, an exception is thrown in the try block, and it doesn't go in to the catch block?  Can you provide a basic example please, to clarify the problem?

Comment: Set a breakpoint on the Throw statement, some odds you'll discover that the code runs on a different thread.  It isn't the kind of exception you should ever catch, in all likelihood it is triggered by a bug in your program.  Maybe you are passing the wrong device guid or id, something like that.  You can't catch and handle bugs, handling a bug requires fixing your code.

Comment: Well it happens if a device doenst support setdeviceEnabled; which does do somethings with kernel.dll's calls.  You might be right that this cannt be catched but i hope its possible.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I made a workaround, despite i didnt want to edit de devicehelper.vb
since multiple progs used it, i had to change it.
I added a variable hideErr and if it is set the Throw New exceptions are skipped. Its realy dirty code i think, to do this, but i saw no other option

Comment: why rate this negative ?, 
i said it is a dirty workaround, i dont see it as a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

Just create your own clas derived from mentioned public class. Next step is to implement your methods like this: (I'm sorry, this code is in C#, but idea should be clear)

```
public {fill return type} MyMethod( /* arguments */)
{
    try {
        return BaseMethod( /* arguments */);      // this method is from base class
    }
    catch(ArgumentException)
    {
    }
}
```

And then just start using your implementation and call your methods.